# Too many redirects MVC project

Tags: owin

I have a .net project using Azure Active Directory as the SSO. Tested and everything works fine locally.

I deployed the project on an environment with 2 load balancer and I started getting error message :

This page isn’t working
xxx.com redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

```
  protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier;

        //This is the line causing the issue
        GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute()); 


    }
```

In chrome at time the site is loaded properly but in IE, there are too many cookies that are being created for OpenId.

I tried this also:

```
      protected void Application_BeginRequest()
      {
         if (!Context.Request.IsSecureConnection)

         Response.Redirect(Context.Request.Url.ToString().Replace("http:", 
        "https:"));
      }
```

I even tried the KentorOwin:

```
         app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType
         (CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseKentorOwinCookieSaver();

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
```

But nothing seems working.

Any help please?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I came to know that the environment I am using is accepting HTTPS as request which then is redirected to HTTP as there are load balancers.

Might be the cause of the probs.